# split file with python into new lines with counter

Tags: python, tabs, split, line

I want to split a file that contains a tab delimited list of words into a "list" with the word preceeded by a number.

So if the input file contains this (where the space between words is a tab):
tree car house blanket

I'd like this output:

```
1 tree
2  car
3  house
4 blanket
```

I've got this code working that prints out the "list of words" but not sure how to get the counter in front of the words:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

with open ("commonwords.tsv") as file:
  for line in file:
    print line.replace("\t","\n")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
import csv
with open("commonwords.tsv") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace("\t", "\n")
        for ind, word in enumerate(line.split(), 1):
            print "{0} {1}".format(ind, word)
1 tree
2 car
3 house
4 blanket
```

Not sure if you want the count to reset each line or continue to the end:

```
with open("commonwords.tsv") as f:
    line = f.read().replace("\t", "\n")
    for ind, word in enumerate(line.split(), 1):
        print "{0} {1}".format(ind, word)
```

You can also just split without replacing:

```
with open("commonwords.tsv") as f:
    lines = f.read().split()
    for ind, word in enumerate(lines, 1):
        print "{0} {1}".format(ind, word)
```

Comment: that doesn't give a number per word.

Comment: Also, got this error- Value error: zero length fieldname in format. Do you know why this error might occur? Thanks

Comment: @Jazzmine, try it now, you must be using an older version of python

Comment: Hi Padraic, I'll try it now - I'm using 2.6 in a VM I obtained. Thanks

Comment: yep, you need to use `{0} {1}` for python 2.6

Comment: I see I need to study enumerate and itertools. I'm pretty new to Python but I definitely need to understand these features. Thank you very much for helping me get past this.

Comment: No prob, you're welcome, yep enumerate and itertools are certainly worth investing some time in.

Answer (score 1):

The enumerate function can count the words for you but you need an iterator or a list of the words, not just the lines of the file. Here's a generator that goes through rows of a csv file and outputs each column individually. its fed through enumerate to get the result.

```
import csv

def yield_col(reader):
    for row in reader:
        for item in row:
            yield item

with open ("commonwords.tsv") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, dialect='excel-tab')
    for num, word in enumerate(yield_col(reader), 1):
        print num, word
```

Comment: This solution worked as well. I gave the green checkmark to Padraic as he provided his answer earlier but thank you tdelaney for providing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('commonwords.tsv') as infile, open('/path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    count = itertools.count(1)
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter'\t'):
        for word in row:
            writer.writerow([next(count), word])
```

Comment: Hi inspectorG4dget, thanks for responding so quickly. I'm getting an error on the comma between infile and open in line 4: Syntax error: Invalid syntax. Were you able to test this?

Comment: @Jazzmine this syntax is for Python 2.7 and above. You're using 2.6, I believe?